# Cypress tagged hooks with mocha

Tags: automation, cucumber, mocha.js, hook, cypress

I have been building ui automation frameworks with Cypress for some time, but always using the Cypress-Cucumber-Preprocessor.

Now I need to build one without cucumber, just plain ol' mocha, but I found a problem. Seems like I can't use tagged hooks to execute code for specific tests (scenarios in Cucumber)

The scenario is basically this. I have a spec file with several tests. I have a "before" hook that seeds test data to a Mongo db, and eventually I might need to add a hook or hooks to execute something (whatever) before a specific test.

With Cucumber you have a way to tag a given scenario (@tag) and then you can create a hook that will be executed ONLY before or after that specific scenario

```
@tag
Scenario: Tagged scenario
  Given condition
  When I do this
  Then I should see that
```

```
before({tag : '@tag'}, () => {
   code
})
```

I haven't found a way to do this with mocha in Cypress... Anyone has found a way?

thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeforeEach or Before, that does predominantly the same thing in Mocha.